# Create React App Typescript: Transpile only, do not type check, do not lint

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app, compiler-optimization

I have a small React project I want to deploy on a Google Compute Engine instance with limited RAM, under 1.5 GB.

When building a production version on my app, the typescript linter and compiler routinely use around 2 GB of RAM to transpile the tiny project, so when I deploy, the Compute Engine instance runs out of ram before the project can be built.

How can I make the Typescript compiler do absolutely nothing but attempt to trasnpile to javascript? No lint check, no ts config rules checks, do absolutely nothing but the bare minimum: transpile the app?

I've looked through all the flags for the tsConfig, and even the least strict option still attempts too much.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the project has been built for production you should have a `build` folder which can be deployed to your Google Compute Engine instance. At this point it's just a collection of HTML, JavaScript, and CSS. The RAM usage should be negligible as there is no transpilation happening at this point, only static files being served.

If, however, you're deploying your entire source to Google Compute Engine and using the "start" npm task then you're transpiling the whole thing right there and then. This is not the recommended approach.

It's best to use a web server like `nginx` or `express` to serve the static files produced by the build.

Comment: I was under the impression built files shouldn't be checked into version control? The entire project is an express server, and I do serve the built static files from it. The start up script runs the typescript build command, spins up the server, then serves the static files. It just runs out of memory during the build stage.

Comment: You're right, built files shouldn't be checked into version control, but that has nothing to do with deployment. It seems like you're most of the way there, and the real problem is you're deploying your source when you really only need the pre-built static files + your express server. There's no reason at all to build the project on the deployment target.

Comment: thanks. I have a noobish question though; how would you deploy the built files unto the sever? I was using git as the deployment system. A quick pull, build, then run.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google cloud specifically, but I would be surprised if they didn't have some form of FTP capability. Or if this is a VM that you have full control over there's nothing stopping you from installing your own FTP server. If it's windows you can use remote desktop to copy the files from your local system. If it's linux and you're connecting via SSH then you can use `scp` to copy files.

Comment: I have full control over the VM, I'll look into using FTP. Thanks! Funny thing is I've already used this for environment variables provided with Google Cloud's metadata server. I can just punt the build directory there and pull it down the same way.

Comment: He is talking about build time issue, not runtime issue.

Comment: @KazuyaGosho Yes, that is what we discussed. This answer does not relate to a runtime issue. I don't understand what you're saying.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No, you can't disable type check with Create React App(CRA).

### Details

There is no way to disable TypeScript check, so all you can do is `eject` or `react-app-rewired` and write your own Babel configuration.
My recommendation is wipe out CRA completely, then write a webpack config on your own, and use ts-loader's `transpileOnly` option with it.

If you just want to compile regardless TS errors, you should set the following environment variable.

```
TSC_COMPILE_ON_ERROR=true
```

It makes CRA to compile even if TypeScript check fails.
However, it does not disable type check, but do not fail with TypeScript errors.